# Can I pause and resume the multipart upload using Amazon High or Low Level API?

Tags: java, file-upload, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, image-uploading

I'm trying to develop an Upload Manager (installable on your PC and will not be a web app) that will upload the selected image files to AmazonS3 using Java. Now, I have done coding to the level that it will initialize the upload and pause it using TransferManager (high level API) from AmazonS3. The problem is, everytime I resume the upload, it starts from the beginning. I have looked at several aws blogs and aws docs but there is no straight forward answer to the question. I have also written code with low level API (using their sample code) but there, I don't know how to pause the upload. So, my question is:

1. How to resume the upload from the point it was paused ?
2. I have two buttons (Using JFrames and Swing Worker) named Pause and Resume. What should I do so that I can Pause and Resume repeatedly ? How do I implement the code ?

   ```
   public class UploadObjectMultipartUploadUsingHighLevelAPI {

   public void pauseUploading(TransferManager tm, Upload upload) throws Exception{
   long MB = 1024 * 1024 ;
   TransferProgress progress = upload.getProgress();
   System.out.println("The pause will occur once 5 MB of data is uploaded");
   while( progress.getBytesTransferred() < 5*MB )
       Thread.sleep(2000);

   boolean forceCancel = true;
   float dataTransfered = (float) upload.getProgress().getBytesTransferred();
   System.out.println("Data Transfered until now: " + dataTransfered);
   PauseResult<PersistableUpload> pauseResult = ((Upload) upload).tryPause(forceCancel);
   System.out.println("The upload has been paused. The code that we've got is " +   pauseResult.getPauseStatus());
   pauseResult = ((Upload) upload).tryPause(forceCancel);
   PersistableUpload persistableUpload = (PersistableUpload) pauseResult.getInfoToResume();
   System.out.println("Storing information into file");
   File f = new File("D:\\Example\\resume-upload");
   if( !f.exists() )
       f.createNewFile();

   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
   persistableUpload.serialize(fos);
   fos.close();
   }

   public void resumeUploading(TransferManager tm) throws Exception{
   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\Example\\resume-upload"));
   System.out.println("Reading information from the file"); 
   PersistableUpload persistableUpload;
   persistableUpload = PersistableTransfer.deserializeFrom(fis);
   System.out.println("Reading information completed");
   System.out.println("The system will resume upload now");
   tm.resumeUpload(persistableUpload);
   fis.close();
   //      System.out.println("Upload complete.");
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   String existingBucketName = "Business.SkySquirrel.RawImages/Test";
   String keyName            = "Pictures1.zip";
   String filePath           = "D:\\Pictures1.zip";
   TransferManagerConfiguration configuration = new TransferManagerConfiguration();
   TransferManager tm = new TransferManager(new ProfileCredentialsProvider()); 
   configuration.setMultipartUploadThreshold(1024 * 1024);
   tm.setConfiguration(configuration);
   System.out.println("************* Upload Manager *************");
   try {
       Upload upload = tm.upload(existingBucketName, keyName, new File(filePath));        
       System.out.println("Upload Started");
       System.out.println("Transfer: " + upload.getDescription());

       UploadObjectMultipartUploadUsingHighLevelAPI multipartPause = 
               new UploadObjectMultipartUploadUsingHighLevelAPI();
       multipartPause.pauseUploading(tm, upload);

       UploadObjectMultipartUploadUsingHighLevelAPI multipartResume = 
               new UploadObjectMultipartUploadUsingHighLevelAPI();
       multipartResume.resumeUploading(tm);
       } 
   catch (AmazonClientException amazonClientException) {
       System.out.println("Unable to upload file, upload was aborted.");
       amazonClientException.printStackTrace();
   }
   }
   }
   ```

I'd appreciate a sample code using either High Level or Low Level APIs of AmazonS3.

I am using version 1.8.9.1 of the SDK. I have also added progress while initializing upload, pausing and resuming with following code.

```
long MB = 1024 * 1024;
    TransferProgress progress = upload.getProgress();
    float dataTransfered = progress.getBytesTransferred();  

    while(!upload.isDone()){
        dataTransfered = progress.getBytesTransferred();
        System.out.println("Data Transfered: " + dataTransfered/MB + " MB");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
```

And I've got following result:

Passwords match
Following Files are selected:

```
D:\Pictures3\DSC02247 - Copy.JPG
Writing 'D:\Pictures3\DSC02247 - Copy.JPG' to zip file
D:\Pictures3\DSC02247.JPG
Writing 'D:\Pictures3\DSC02247.JPG' to zip file
D:\Pictures3\DSC02248.JPG
Writing 'D:\Pictures3\DSC02248.JPG' to zip file
************* Upload Manager *************
Upload Started
Transfer: Uploading to *******/****/****.zip
Data Transfered: 0.0 MB
Data Transfered: 0.0703125 MB
Data Transfered: 0.21875 MB
Data Transfered: 0.3203125 MB
Data Transfered: 0.4140625 MB
Data Transfered: 0.515625 MB
....
....
Data Transfered: 0.9609375 MB
Data Transfered: 1.0546875 MB
Pause Commencing
The pause will occur once 5 MB of data is uploaded
Data Transfered: 1.09375 MB
Data Transfered: 1.1640625 MB
Data Transfered: 1.265625 MB
Data Transfered: 1.359375 MB
....
....
Data Transfered: 4.734375 MB
Data Transfered: 4.8359375 MB
Data Transfered: 4.9296875 MB
The upload has been paused. The code that we've got is SUCCESS
Storing information into file
Upload Paused
Resume Commencing
Reading information from the file
Reading information completed
The system will resume upload now
Data Transfered: 0.0 MB
Data Transfered: 0.171875 MB
Data Transfered: 0.265625 MB
Data Transfered: 0.359375 MB
Data Transfered: 0.421875 MB
....
....
Data Transfered: 9.58182 MB
Data Transfered: 9.683382 MB
Data Transfered: 9.753695 MB
Upload Complete
```

Answer (score 3):

With the REST API, this is trivially simple... you "pause" by just not sending any more parts, and you "resume" by sending the next part.

The "low level API" maps closely to the REST interface, so the functionality should be the same.  S3, internally, has no concept of "pausing" a multipart upload.  It's just waiting -- indefinitely -- for you to upload more parts and complete the request, or to abort the request.  It will store the parts you've sent (with charges for storage) until the entire operation is completed or aborted... and it will literally wait for *months* (I've seen it... and presumably, it will wait forever) for you to "resume."

But there are no low-level calls for pause/resume -- you just do it.

The catch is, you have to hold on, locally, to the etags for each part, and you have to send them along with the request to complete the multipart upload.

If you never complete or abort a multipart operation, the parts you did send are stored by S3, waiting for your next move.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/llJavaUploadFile.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that the question was based on C# code, even though we implement this in Java I think it is the same thing, that is, following the same idea you can build this in whatever language it is allowed, it's about concepts, not syntax or language's feature.

In our case, **it is not only about to Play/Pause**, but **it is mainly about a System/Environment Crash** that could happen while you are uploading a **60GB** file, so we could restart the upload from the last point where the problem occurred (one byte after the last byte successfully uploaded), not from the beginning again, that's the point.

In order to achieve this, we have to track some info while we are uploading our MultiPartUpload file, without them it will not be possible to restart anything. So for each successfully Block of bytes uploaded, keep track (save) the following info, we will need them:

- (**Bucket**) Name of the Bucket
- (**Key**) The exact name of the object key (file name), must be the same
- (**UploadId**) The uploadId that was stopped/crashed
- (**File**) The local file to resume its upload *(just to mention)*
- (**partSize**) Size Block in bytes to be uploaded *(technically it is not necessary to follow the same block size used before, 
          it only need to be sure to start at the right byte, that is, the byte right after the last byte successfully uploaded already)*
- (**startFilePosition**) That's the position in bytes of the file where the upload will be resumed, must be the byte right after the last one successfully uploaded before
- (**List PartETag**) The list of PartETag successfully already uploaded (constructed with the PartNumber and the eTag info)

A Collection List of PartETag must be created and filled with those already uploaded before. These PartETags we received when have uploaded a File Block Bytes successfully:

```
  UploadPartResult uploadResult = s3.uploadPart(uploadRequest);
  partETags.add(uploadResult.getPartETag()); // <-- keep tracked
```

Then, later on, we can recreate the List of PartETag to restart where we have being stopped:

```
  List<PartETag> partETags = new ArrayList<PartETag>();
  partETags.add(new PartETag(1, "3beb7e9af8674013a48d78ba14b4b075"));
  partETags.add(new PartETag(2, "5bfdc19fa1fa7b7b347f2c13a500d14c"));
  partETags.add(new PartETag(3, "ef18c3c8c4b3162258a35c3bf424bc15"));
  partETags.add(new PartETag(4, "f31091770d8053754a02715dca601fa3"));
  partETags.add(new PartETag(5, "f31aa43f51fba0f8991eb3971a9c55b0"));
```

With all this in hands, we can restart/resume the Upload, taking into account the sequence and FilePosition (in bytes) exactly after where we stopped (or crashed):

```
  UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest()
                .withBucketName(bucket)
                .withKey(key)
                .withUploadId(initResponse.getUploadId())
                .withPartNumber(sequence) // 
                .withFileOffset(filePosition)
                .withFile(file)
                .withPartSize(partSize);

// sequence = (Last PartNumber Uploaded) + 1 (In the sample here, must be 6)
// filePosition = LastBytePosition Uploaded + (Block Size Bytes)
```

In our case, it worked very well.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the SDK are you using?

The reason I'm asking is because in older versions of the SDK, if you resumed an upload/download, the progress would start off from the resumed point instead of the beginning, thus always showing 0 bytes or 0%.

The TransferManager API that you are using should provide resume/pause so you really shouldn't need to use the low level API, unless there's some functionality you want which is not provided by the high level API.

Other reasons the upload might start from the beginning is because you paused before a chunk was transferred, you are using encryption, or the file is not big enough. In your situation I would guess that none of these is the case and you are just encountering the bug though.

If you are using the newest version and are still encountering problems please let me know!

Comment: I am using version 1.8.9.1. I have also added progress

Comment: Hello Richard, please see the output that I get when using progress.getBytesTransfered() after initial upload, pause and resume. Is this a bug or I'm doing something wrong ?

Comment: Hi, I'm going to have to ask you to make some changes, so let's try debugging this issue together. Instead of pausing at exactly 5MB, can you instead try pausing at 6 or 7MB? The problem is that although the chunk size might be 5MB, I'm not 100% sure but I think the bytes transferred might include required metadata, which would mean you are pausing before the entire chunk is sent.

Comment: Actually, since you are using Thread.sleep() I'm skeptical that this is the problem now, although it's worth a try anyway. I'm going to get someone who knows the code base better to see if he can help you

Comment: I tried pausing after 7 MB but still getting the same result as shown above.